# Imagemagick failing to convert from tif to jpg

Tags: azure, ubuntu, imagemagick

I am using ImageMagick on ubuntu 16.04 machine in Azure to convert from tif to jpg. For most of the files it works perfect, but failing for few files with the error, 

**convert: tif_jpeg.c:975: JPEGSetupDecode: Assertion `sp->cinfo.comm.is_decompressor' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)**

I have no clue on this error, can someone please help me resolve this error.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by downgrading libtiff from libtiff.so.5.2.6 to libtiff.so.5.2.4 with ImageMagick version 7.0.7-7 Q16. Even if we do ImageMagick upgrade to 7.0.8.11 Q16, downgrade of libtiff is still required. As said by fmw42, tiff file might be created using older JPG compression and so downgrade worked here. Thanks @Mark and @fmw42 for all the helpful thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your TIFF file uses some quite modern compression method (JBIG2 for example) and your **ImageMagick** is maybe outdated.

Try using:

```
tiffinfo YourImage.tif
```

to see the compression settings.

Try updating **ImageMagick**. You can get your installed version with:

```
identify -version
```

The modern world is on v7.0.8

Try updating your `libtiff` package too.

Comment: Thank you Mark for your reply. **Compression Scheme: JPEG**. This is what I got after running tiffinfo. ImageMagick is updated in my machine.**Version: ImageMagick 7.0.8-11 Q16 x86_64 2018-09-03.**

Comment: I tried updating libtiff, even it is also the latest version **libtiff5 is already installed at the latest version (4.0.6-1ubuntu0.4), so it will not be upgraded.** Can you please suggest how can I proceed on this error. Also, how can I make convert to point to JBIG2, if I update..please help

Comment: Can you share an *"unhappy"* file that causes errors?

Comment: Another option might be to prefix your input file with `TIFF64:` like this `convert TIFF64:image.tif result.jpg`.

Comment: convert: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 70 `/home/pftadmin/TIff_Test/not_working/56608512-a5e3-4b1d-be40-3072e6fb2068_notworking_output.jpeg' @ error/jpeg.c/JPEGErrorHandler/332.

Comment: I am getting the above error, when I try running the command.
 libjpeg.so.8 was installed and listed in ldd of convert. I removed and installed libjpeg.62, even then it is not pointing to that. But I can see a 0KB output file is being created in the destination.
I have installed JBIG2 but  ldd on convert is not showing up there. I think I am somewhat progressive now.Please help.Thanks

Comment: Let me know what other info is needed from me.Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure what else to suggest other than you sharing the *"unhappy"* TIFF. Maybe Fred @fmw42 will have some bright ideas.

Comment: Thank you Mark. Unfortunately, i can't share the file coz it is customer file, I will check for any other test asset is available..

Comment: If the file uses the older JPG compression, then ImageMagick may not be able to process it. It depends upon libtiff, which ImageMagick uses as a delegate and also possibly libjpeg, if jpg compressed. I can test if you provide an example image that fails.

Comment: Thanks @fmw42 can you list down the binaries   and versions that I may have to update to resolve this issue. I am trying to get a sample file. In the mean time I will update the required binaries.

Comment: If the tiff was compressed with an old type JPG compression, my understanding is that the current libtiff cannot deal with it. I am not sure if libjpeg is involved or not. If it were me I would upgrade both. But I fear that your TIFF file was created with a tool that uses the old style JPEG compression and I do not know what tools might read it. If you can find some other tool that reads and writes the tif, then recompress it, hopefully, with a current JPG compression scheme. You might ask on the ImageMagick forum (https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/) or some TIFF forum.

Comment: CONTINUED: You will also have to install the delegate that does the JBIG2 compression, I suspect, to recompress in that format, provided that libtiff supports it. This may also be relevant about the old style JPG with libtif. See https://github.com/openpreserve/format-corpus/tree/master/tiff-examples/old-style-jpeg-compression also http://www.libtiff.org/internals.html

Comment: In this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIFF, you will find a list of compression options for TIFF and what versions of TIFF support them. Looks like JBIG2 needs TIFF-FX extension and old JPEG is superseded by new JPEG and needs TIFF 6.